# OG menu default links are not adding up

Tags: routes, organic-groups

I am using og_menu 7.x-3.x-dev I am trying to create some default links to the og menu, but links are not adding.With a new group node its creating the og menu but the default links are not coming.Do I need to apply any patch? Thanks in advance. On the og menu settings page I have checked the "Automatically create a OG Menu for new Organic Group" checkbox and in the default links section I have tried adding absolute url and internal drupal path but no success.Am I missing some settings.

Comment: I can see the links are added in the database but they are not showing up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure out later the link I was adding were actually the nodes I was creating programmatically as a new group is created and I was creating the path alias programmatically as well, when i check the db table menu_links I found there was no router for these node menu links,so to make them work I am putting the default links as external urls for example `http://yoursite/node/test`, I believe there must be a better way to get this done,good for now.